# How do i remove duplicates in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, duplicates

I have a database which consists of few collections , i have tried copying from one collection to another .
In this process connection was lost and had to recopy them
now i find around 40000 records duplicates.

Format of my data:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("555abaf625149715842e6788"), 
    "reviewer_name" : "Sudarshan A", 
    "emp_name" : "Wilson Erica", 
    "evaluation_id" : NumberInt(550056), 
    "teamleader_id" : NumberInt(17199), 
    "reviewer_id" : NumberInt(1659), 
    "team_manager" : "Las Vegas", 
    "teammanager_id" : NumberInt(12245), 
    "team_leader" : "Thomas Donald", 
    "emp_id" : NumberInt(7781)
}
```

here only evaluation id is unique.

Queries that i have tried:

```
ensureIndex({id:1}, {unique:true, dropDups:true})
```

Comment: `ensureIndex({_id:1}, {unique:true, dropDups:true})`. Did you forget the underscore?

Comment: If `emp_id` is unique then try this `ensureIndex({"emp_id":1}, {"unique":true, "dropDups":true})`

Comment: Which indexes have you got in the table?
Which version of Mongo have you got?

Comment: dropDups was removed in mongo v.3

Comment: According to my knowledge _id will no have duplicate what ever be the case

Comment: So you have to choose another field to remove dups

Comment: usually I would go with `db.coll.find().forEach(function(doc) { db.coll2.save(doc); });` then there will not be any duplicates even if you have to recopy them. So how did you do it exactly?

Comment: how many times do you need to de-duplicate this data?

Comment: i have 3 lakhs of records in one collection and 1.5 lacs in other ,while moving them connection was lost i had to redo it again now i have 4.9 lacs instead of 4.5 lacs .Ineed to get rid of those 49 thousand records

Comment: Is there a allternate for dropDups after ensuring index have also tried sarsing but no luck

Comment: Finally found te solution.....

Answer (score 0):

dropDups was removed in mongodb ~2.7.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30187688/mongo-3-duplicates-on-unique-index-dropdups?answertab=oldest#tab-top.) is other realization method

but I don't test it

Comment: “While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.”