# How to make a column for MongoDB to be primary key like happens in SQL Server and avoid duplicate records?

Tags: mongodb, duplicates, primary-key

How to add a primary key to a specific column in MongoDB?

How to avoid duplicate records in MongoDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a unique index on the field
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/

Comment: okay , thank you @njLT
How about removing the Duplicate records

Comment: if you have the unique index from the start - you won't have duplicate records. take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30187688/mongo-3-duplicates-on-unique-index-dropdups

Comment: see over here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14184099/fastest-way-to-remove-duplicate-documents-in-mongodb

Comment: I want to make combination of 2 columns as unique key @Avij

Comment: If you are looking at the solution mentioned in link before...try adding another field here in group : _id: { name: "$name",anotherField:'$anotherField'}, @PriyankaBaviskar

Comment: create a unique index on the field https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/ 
this link worked perfect for me

Answer (score 1):

_id is the default reserved id for the mongodb object and that's an unique id.
refer that link it will help you to get the idea of unique id http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/BSON